# How to update react component with new data via react-apollo?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

**Workflow**

- User login to the app
- He will see a list of item fetched using `queries`(Works fine)
- Now, he will add an item in another page(adding using normal POST call, not using graphQL)
- When he comes to the listing page, the new entry will not be there :(

How to solve this? I understood, `apollo` is maintaining a cache. So, it doesn't make any request.

I want to force `refetch` the data from the server every time I load the listing page.

How can this be done?

Comment: There are two ways to do this, one is with [database normalization](http://dev.apollodata.com/react/cache-updates.html#normalization), another is with [subscriptions](http://dev.apollodata.com/react/subscriptions.html) both will give you the effect you seek.

Comment: @mstorkson Thanks for your suggestions. I think, it can be solved with "fetchPolicy". http://dev.apollodata.com/react/api-queries.html#graphql-config-options-fetchPolicy

Comment: That might work, but if you properly set up your application, changes to the data store should automatically result in UI updates. You are adding with "post" though, which means your object may not end up in the apollo cache. Have you used the apollo tool to see if your object does indeed end up there?

Comment: @mstorkson Actually "fetchPolicy" solved my problem. Thanks for your suggestion though.

Comment: > "adding using normal POST call, not using graphQL"
is there a reason you're not using apollo to perform the mutation? if you used a mutation you could use their `updateQueries` function to update the cache!

Comment: @nburk Thanks for your suggestions. The backend is not fully ready with graphQL. For the first cut, we just implemented GET. We'll add mutation later. Using "fetchPolicy" fixed the issue temporarily.